# Play authenticate (Deadbolt) restrict tag in view script not being processed

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I have a working web application that uses the deadbolt module.

Every thing is working fine except that I am unable to add the restrict tag to a view script. I have tried..

```
@@Restrict( @@Group( "user"  )  ) {
       <p> Howdy </p>
}

#{deadbolt.restrict roles:[['user']]}
         <p> Howdy </p>
#{/deadbolt.restrict}
```

Both of the above simply get displayed on the page, as text, without interpolation.

However the following works correctly....

@subjectNotPresent() {

Howdy

}

tia, Chet

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to use deadbolt 1 (which is for Play 1.x) in a Play 2.x application.
Instead of deadbolt-1 you should use [deadbolt-2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2).

Then it will look something like this:

```
@import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.views.html._
...
@pattern("permission-name") {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Actually I had already tried that, I failed to mention it in my original post.

@Restrict(  List(as( "user" ) ) ){
   <p>Howdy</p>
}

gives the error....
   object be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.Restrict is not a value

I have @import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.Restrict; at the top

Thanks, Chet

Comment: Actually I am using
    @Restrict( handler, List(as( "user" ) ) ){
I am not sure if "handler" needs to be replaced with something.